# Webscrape Flashscore with Python/Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I started to learn scrape websites with Python and Selenium. I choose selenium because I need to navigate through the website and I also have to login.

I wrote an script that is able to open a firefox window and it opens the website www.flashscore.com. With this script I also be able to login and navigate to the different sports section (main menu) they have.

The code:

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# open website
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flashscore.com")

# login
driver.find_element_by_id('signIn').click()

username = driver.find_element_by_id("email")
password = driver.find_element_by_id("passwd")

username.send_keys("*****")
password.send_keys("*****")

driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

# go to the tennis section
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Tennis')
link.click()

#go to the live games tab in the tennis section

# ?????????????????????????????'
```

---

Then it went more difficult. I also want to navigate to, for example, the sections "live games" and "finished" tabs in the sports sector. This part wouldn't work. I tried many things but I can't get into one of this tabs. When analyzing the website I see that they use some Iframes. I also find some code to switch to a Iframes window. But the problem is, I can't find the name of the Iframe where the tabs are that I want to click on. Maybe the Iframes are not the problem and do I look to the wrong way. (Maybe the problem is caused by some javascript?)

Can anybody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the iframes are not the problem in this case. The "Live games" element is not inside an `iframe`. Locate it by link text and click:

```
live_games_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text("LIVE Games")
live_games_link.click()
```

You may need to *wait for this link to be clickable* before actually trying to click it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

live_games_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "LIVE Games")))
live_games_link.click()
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reaction. One problem. I get an error when running my script.

Comment: When running this: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# open website
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.flashscore.com")

#go to the live games tab in the tennis section
live_games_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "LIVE Games")))
live_games_link.click()

Comment: I get the error:    live_games_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "LIVE Games")))
NameError: name 'wait' is not defined

Comment: I have it working. I just the line: driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds. Then it works for me. Many thanks for putting me on the right line!